# discordjs return total users in forEach?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I did try this code :

```
message.client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
     console.log(guild.memberCount)
})
```

and it returns like this:

```
300
200
100
etc
```

How to get a total in one go like them all together so it shows up like 600 instead all seperate.
I know there is an other code that shows all the users in the guild, but i just want to know how to do it this way, so i can expand the code and filter them on presence.

i just dont know how to total the value in a forEach or map

regards

//UPDATE I need to get it working like this method,
this shows like the above log:
100
200
300

```
  client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
     const total = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "online").size
     console.log("per 1", total)
    
    
     
     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
const totalUsers = message.client.guilds.cache.map(el => el.memberCount).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
```

Comment: Personally I would also reach for reduce.  That said I answered using forEach because it is likely easier for OP to understand(given the basic original question).

Comment: also thanks for your reaction, i get this very long value 480506285482180627514895624454537216670

Comment: I edited my answer. I forgot to only do it over memberCount property. Now it basically works like this: it creates a new array with 'memberCount' values using Array.map() and then sums it up using Array.reduce().

PS. You're probably right about not using the reduce but it can be an opportunity for OP to learn something new

Comment: many thanks, it works, im still learning, and i understand now how it works. but how can i use it with .filter option ?  look at the end of my descriptiion above if u have time.

Comment: If you want to retrieve only active users from one guild you can do `const total = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "online").length`. And if you want to get number of active users from all guilds you need to somehow combine it with my answer. It's kind of hard get the exact answer because I don't know the exact discord API structure.

Comment: aah ok no worries, i will try how to get the active users of all guilds. thanks for answering my question, as it helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function like:

```
   function arrSum(arr){
        total = 0;  
        arr.forEach(function(key){
            total = total + key;            
        });
        return total;
    }
```

and use it like:

```
arrSum(message.client.guilds.cache);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reaction, if i do that i get a value thats super super high. using console.log (total)

Answer (score 1):

You could use map + reduce chaining...you can retrieve the 'memberCount' with the mapping and summing the actual values with the reduce:

```
    const guilds = [
    { memberCount: 100 },
    { memberCount: 200 },
    { memberCount: 300 },
    { memberCount: 400 }
];

const totalMembers = guilds
  .map((guild) => guild.memberCount)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);

console.log(totalMembers);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and helping me, i'm still learning but i am understanding now how it works

Comment: that works, but how can i implement it working like this ? look my example

Comment: Hi Hector, you would like to sum the number of members with the presence?.status equals to online?